# MiKTeX can't build format of platex/platex-dev

Tags: miktex, format-files, platex

The latest `MiKTeX` supports the `pTeX/upTeX` engine now, but when I build the platex format, there is an error:

```
This is e-pTeX, Version 3.141592653-p4.0.0-220214-2.6 (utf8.euc) (MiKTeX 22.3) (INITEX)  1 JUL 2022 20:40
entering extended mode
 restricted \write18 enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**D:/MiKTeX/tex/platex/config/platex.ini
(D:/MiKTeX/tex/platex/config/platex.ini
<<< making "platex with Babel" format >>>

(D:\MiKTeX\tex/platex/base\platex.ltx (D:\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\latex.ltx
(D:\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\texsys.cfg)
\openout15 = `texsys.aux'.


./texsys.aux found


\@currdir set to: ./.


Assuming \openin and \input 
have the same search path.


Defining UNIX/DOS style filename parser.

catcodes, registers,
\@inputcheck=\read0
\@unused=\write0
\maxdimen=\dimen10
\hideskip=\skip10
\p@=\dimen11
\z@=\dimen12
\z@skip=\skip11
\voidb@x=\box10
 parameters,
\normalbaselineskip=\skip12
\normallineskip=\skip13
\normallineskiplimit=\dimen13
\interfootnotelinepenalty=\count23
\strutbox=\box11

LaTeX2e <2022-06-01> patch level 3
(D:\MiKTeX\tex/latex/l3kernel\expl3.ltx
(D:\MiKTeX\tex/latex/l3kernel\expl3-code.tex
Package: expl3 2022-06-16 L3 programming layer (code)
\c_max_int=\count24
\l_tmpa_int=\count25
...
\l__coffin_display_x_dim=\dimen44
\l__coffin_display_y_dim=\dimen45

! Undefined control sequence.
l.31703 \scan_new:N \s__text_stop
                                 
No pages of output.
```

I don't know why `\scan_new:N \s__text_stop` is not defined? There is no error when building uplatex format. All packages are the latest version.

Answer (score 1):

this issue already fixed in MikTeX [issue 1120](https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex/issues/1120).